# Python3.6 - Plotting lat/long co-ordinates on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my first time using Matplotlib. I have a series of latitude and longitude co-ordinates in two lists, and I want to represent these in a meaningful manner. I would not like to use Basemap for [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223703/installing-basemap-with-python3-6-on-ubuntu-18-04).

```
lat = ['35.905333', '35.896389', '35.901281', '35.860491', '35.807607', '35.832267', '35.882414', '35.983794', '35.974463', '35.930951']
long = ['14.471970', '14.477780', '14.518173', '14.572245', '14.535320', '14.455894', '14.373217', '14.336096', '14.351006', '14.401137']
```

I am trying to represent these in a meaningful manner using Matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(lat, long)
plt.show()
```

However my figure is as follows:

[image]

I am unable to set the axis in order to obtain a meaningful representation of these coordinates. How can this be done? What am I doing wrong?

I am looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get the expected outcome.

[image]

I have also tried to [plot on a cartesian coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430231/how-i-can-get-cartesian-coordinate-system-in-matplotlib).

---

**EDIT:**

As per the comment below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(lat, long)
plt.axis('square')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Try doing `plt.axis('equal')` or `plt.axis('sqaure')` to get the desired effect. [Source](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axis.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however this does not set the axis correctly. I also tried setting specific x and y ranges, but this did not work.

Comment: Your numbers are strings. Convert them to floats

Comment: You need to change the type of the lists `lat` and `long` (may be also the name for long). Try, `lat = np.array(['35.905333', '35.896389', '35.901281', '35.860491', '35.807607', '35.832267', '35.882414', '35.983794', '35.974463', '35.930951'], dtype=float)`

Comment: @DavidG, cannot believe I overlooked this. Read data from file and missed the conversion. It worked.

Comment: Use Basemap.  Geographical coordinates ***must*** be projected on the plot plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, change the type to float:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lat = np.array(['35.905333', '35.896389', '35.901281', '35.860491', '35.807607', 
'35.832267', '35.882414', '35.983794', '35.974463', '35.930951'], dtype=float)
long = np.array(['14.471970', '14.477780', '14.518173', '14.572245', '14.535320', 
'14.455894', '14.373217', '14.336096', '14.351006', '14.401137'], dtype=float)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.scatter(lat, long)
# ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, also `ax.scatter(long, lat)` to actually represent on how points were taken from map

Comment: Maybe your answer suffices for the OP's aims but (BUT) geographical coordinates should be projected...

Comment: Upvote for `ax.axis('equal')`